# How can I perform hashing algorithms once I had sign the pdf file by using PSPDFKIT

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to perform hashing to the signed pdf and send it to others. At the same time, the generated hash value will also be send to others. May I know how can I code by using PSPDFKIT?

Answer (score 0):

PSPDFKit supports the following hashing algorithms:

- MD4
- MD5
- SHA-2 (SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512, SHA-512-256)

Please refer to our official documentation for Digital Signatures: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/features/digital-signatures/

For future questions about PSPDFKit, please reach out to our support portal at pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - we're happy to provide support there for our commercial SDK.